# Is there a way to set up a new apple ID without a phone?

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I want to create a new appleID that has no connection to my prior appleID, and still be able to use both of them at will.

Because Apple insists of 2nd Factor authorization, this means you need to use a phone number for this, or SOME OTHER FORM OF 2FA

Is there a way to create a new apple ID either without 2fa, or to use an alternate to a phone number for 2fa authentication?

In principle you can use a security fob to generate a key.  These seem to be pricey.

Or I could use a second phone just for this.

am I missing something.

---

2FA by this method isn't what it's cracked up to be.

If I run Messages on my computer, then any text messages sent to my phone also show up on messages.  So if my computer is compromised, both sources of authentication come to the same place, just different apps.

Comment: How do you intend to keep the payment information separate? I have a work AppleID and personal AppleID that are highly disconnected, so this is easily accomplished with some hardware and a second phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same phone number for two different Apple IDs. If you want anonymity, you'll want to acquire a second phone number.

In the example you provided, since your computer is registered to show your SMS numbers then the computer is one of the "2nd factors" alongside the phone. If you don't want SMS 2FA you'll have to set up a security key.